# Ruby: How to make only one single method in a class public?

Tags: ruby, class, methods, private

Every discussion of private vs. public Ruby methods in a class shows how to declare all following methods private (or public or protected):

```
class airplane
  def preflight
  end

  def engine_start
    return unless preflight_complete?
  end

  private

  def preflight_complete?
  end
end
```

That works great most of the time, where you put all your public methods at the top, and all your private methods down below.

I've got a good-sized class with three public methods, and a few dozen private ones. The private ones are all sequenced in a logical manner for developer comfort.

Now, I find there are 2 or 3 formerly-private methods I need to make public. I don't want to pull them to the top, away from their contextual neighbors. I also find it cludgey to flop back and forth between `public` and `private` each time. This is particularly annoying if the screen size pushes the `public` flag out of view and it's not obvious that a second or third new method are unintentionally public just because I inserted them after the loner public method.

So, is there a graceful way to avoid flopping public/private back and forth to make just one method public?

Comment: To be honest, the **premise** of your question is probably the real problem here: *"I've got a good-sized class with three public methods, and a few dozen private ones"*. A class with "a few dozen" methods sounds massively bloated; a violation of the [Single-Responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle) (see also: the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)), and generally very complex to manage.

Comment: Sure, you could define `public`/`private` methods inline, but fundamentally having 40+ methods in a single class is going to cause bigger problems regardless. **For example**, maybe it would have been better to define a separate `AirplaneTank` class, which exposes a `#full?` public method, instead of bundling all of this into a single `Airplane` [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Comment: @TomLord: extracting a wrong abstraction is often worse than leaving it alone. In my experience anyway.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm not claiming to know the right abstraction here, because all I've seen is 5 method names with no implementation details/context. I'm just giving an example of a potential abstraction. But certainly, a monster class containing 40+ methods is screaming "I need abstracting!" in my experience.

Comment: @TomLord "a monster class containing 40+ methods is screaming "I need abstracting!" in my experience." - that I 100% agree with.

Answer (score 2):

Just put `public` (or private, protected) at the start of the method definition:

```
class airplane
  def preflight
  end

  def engine_start
    return unless preflight_complete?
  end

  private

  def preflight_complete?
  end

  public def tanks_full?
  end

  def pilot_authorized?
  end
end
```

In this case, `pilot_authorized?` is still private, but anyone chan check `tanks_full?`

Comment: That's a nice trick, for sure, but I'd argue that it does more harm than good. A method becoming part of public API is a big enough change to warrant a bigger diff footprint (that would result from moving it higher, into the public section).

Comment: I agree completely, Sergio. In my (real word) case, it is still a very "internal" method that doesn't require advertising. However, another class present in a callback needs to call this from an unusual place. I could use `send :tanks_full?`, but I'm more inclined to make the method public, even if it doesn't merit top billing.  Thanks for the perspective!

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can publish this method via a public wrapper.

```rb
class airplane
  def preflight
  end

  def engine_start
    return unless preflight_complete?
  end

  def tanks_full?
    _tanks_full?
  end

  private

  def preflight_complete?
  end

  def _tanks_full?
  end

  def pilot_authorized?
  end
end
```

This way your code is still clearly divided into two sections, without any surprise defectors, and the method is still near its contextual neighbors.

Answer (score 1):

This seems the most readable to me:

```
class Example
    def public_method1
    end

    private def used_by_public_method1
    end
    
    private def also_used_by_public_method1
    end

    def public_method2
    end
        
    private def used_by_public_method2
    end

    def public_method3
    end
end
```